# import external modules in spark python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have a EMR job with pyspark application. My Code includes some external packages and some files for look up.

This is the hierarchy of file system when i tried the same in local box.

```
[1] Wordcount.py -> spark file
[2] Temp.py -> external packages
[3] files/
        -you have some files which will be used by temp.py
```

**Further Details:**
               When I run the WorkCount.py it imports temp.py in it. The files folder contains some model files. The temp.py internally use those model files.In local box i kept all the code at one place and run the job, it worked fine there

**It works fine in localbox but failing when i run in cluster**

```
[1] No module temp found
[2] No *** file does not exist
```

Can someone tell me how should i have to organize this in EMR cluster such that i can run this smoothly.

Comment: you can zip your module and add have it be distributed to the cluster with `--py-files 'yourzip.zip'` is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work for me . And also i have to install pandas and other packages across the cluster